# PHP getting data using POST and cURL retrieves partial data

Tags: php, json, post, curl, http-post

I'm using the following code to send a POST request to a website to aggregate some Json. I'm successful, only I get only partial data. 
The Json I'm supposed to get contains two objects: 
The first one I get complete.
The second one is a string, a Very long one, and I only get the beginning of it.

I thought I might need to define max length of return value or something but the same code (with different URL) gets another Jsons who also contains objects that are Very long strings no problem.

Can someone please help me understand what I'm missing here?

```
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01';
$header[] = 'Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch';
$header[] = 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4';
$header[] = 'Connection:keep-alive';
$header[] = 'Host:www.host.com';
$header[] = 'Origin:http://www.origin.com';
$header[] = 'Referer:http://www.site.com/something/';
$header[] = 'X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest';

$data = "neededData...";

$process = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, $this->headers_html);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent);
if ($this->cookies == TRUE)
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file);
if ($this->cookies == TRUE)
    curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_ENCODING, $this->compression);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$return = curl_exec($process);
```

Comment: did you try making the request with another tool, say unix curl?

Comment: Nope. Tried with just an html form.. works.

Comment: A little test showed the same exact code gets me the full Json on Linux, but not on Windows (8).

Answer (score 0):

Well, updating my PHP version to the latest one did the trick.
And the Linux machine I testes the code on was running latest version of PHP so that's why it worked there.